# Having trouble in creating exe file for python script

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller

I used py2exe to make an exe of my Python script but when I run the exe file it gives me `matplotlib data file missing` error. What can I do for this thing?

Also I tried using pyInstaller but when everything was completed there was a run time error saying that `application failed to start side by side configuration pyinstaller`.

I am importing these files in my Python script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from SimpleCV import *
import SimpleCV
import random
import time
```

Is there some workarounds or a proper solution I need it badly!

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds and information for several modules on [py2exe website](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules). For matplotlib [check this](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib)

```
import matplotlib
...
setup(
    ...
    data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
)
```

Comment: thanks. i am able to make an exe from py2exe but now its saying orange library not installed used in machine learning. actually my script uses some machine learning function of simpleCV library. So, what do suggest me to do?

Comment: the error is while generating the .exe? or when running?

Comment: while running the exe!

Comment: Check if its been included inside the zip file. If you are bundling everything inside the .exe, try without, so you'll be able to inspect the zip file. There is a problem in py2exe with egg packages. Is orange installed as an egg on your system?

Comment: Please post the error you are getting, I don't know orange library, it may need some extra work